# Google Appengine Logging issues

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, logging

Thank you for your advice on logging.  As I mentioned, 
I tried including my own filter class in the 
logging.properties file:

Here is my appengine-.xml file that points to the
logging-properties file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>uthreee</application>
  <version>1</version>

  <!--
    Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
  -->
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

</appengine-web-app>
```

---

Here is the logging-properties file

```
# A default java.util.logging configuration.
# (All App Engine logging is through java.util.logging by default).
#
# To use this configuration, copy it into your application's WEB-INF
# folder and add the following to your appengine-web.xml:
# 
# <system-properties>
#   <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
# </system-properties>
#
java.util.logging.FileHandler.filter=F

# Set the default logging level for all loggers to WARNING
.level = FINEST
```

---

And , here is F.java

```
import java.util.logging.Filter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class F implements Filter {
public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord lr) {
String Str = lr.getSourceClassName();
Str = Str.toUpperCase();
int pos1;
pos = Str.indexOf("STATUS");
pos1 =
System.out.println ("pos "+pos);
if (pos>=0) {
  return false;
}
else {
  return true;
}
}}
```

---

This is the log information I want suppressed:

```
2015-05-28 18:00:12.207 /api/get/status?_=1432861201589 200 19ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0 module=default version=1
I 2015-05-28 18:00:12.196 StatusServlet doGet: entering status servlet 1
I 2015-05-28 18:00:12.196 GenerationUtil TimerOK: Timer OK d:Fri May 29 01:00:12 UTC 2015 e: Fri May 15 14:47:30 UTC 2015Logical:true
D 2015-05-28 18:00:12.200 GenerationUtil currentSizeOfGeneration: FINE: Generation 1 currently has 10 chromosomes.
I 2015-05-28 18:00:12.200 GenerationUtil checkForQuorum: check quorum returning true
I 2015-05-28 18:00:12.200 StatusServlet doGet: TIMER OK true Q true
I 2015-05-28 18:00:12.200 StatusServlet doGet: HERE C
I 2015-05-28 18:00:12.200 GenerationUtil getCount: DEBUG: get Count status (ga) = 1 Key|generation(1)|
D 2015-05-28 18:00:12.206 GenerationUtil getCount: DEBUG: gcf; count 2
D 2015-05-28 18:00:12.206 GenerationUtil getCount: returning for gen1 value is 2
I 2015-05-28 18:00:12.206 GenerationUtil checkForSufficientRatings: DEBUG: check for Sufficient Ratings 1 count 2quorum 4
I 2015-05-28 18:00:12.206 GenerationUtil checkForSufficientRatings: DEBUG: insufficient ratings , returning false
I 2015-05-28 18:00:12.206 StatusServlet doGet: DEBUG:1 false
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/ AppEngine uses java.util.logging but you can write a facade and use your own class. I personally use slf4j which i also recommend. Even if you disable logging for a servlet the url will still show in the logs because the log also shows the requests themselves. Also check your `logging.properties` file for your minimum logging level. If you use your own facade you can use `FINEST` as your setting.

Comment: Thank you for sharing with me the link to "Logs Java API Overview"

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/

That tells one the API to retrieve logs that already recorded
on the Google appengine system.    It does not tell how
one can control what was logged in the first place.

Thanks for mentioning that one can write the facade 
or use slf4j.  However, I do not see documentation on how
to tell Google Appengine to use either of these.


Should I create my own Filter class and
simply use in logging.properties,
 property java.util.logger.FileHandler.filter?

Comment: Those are a lot of different questions. To use slf4j you need to put the jars of slf4j-api and slf4j-jdk14 in your classpath. Again: App Engine uses `java.util.logging`. You might want to check the docs of `java.util.logging`. The bridge between app engine and java.util.logging is described here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging

Answer (score 0):

The LogManager classloader [can't see your custom filter class](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6878454).  The logging.properties is really only good for installing the standard handlers and setting log levels in GAE.  If you want to install a custom filter you have to use a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) write code to manually install the filter.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about the `ServletContextListener`.
However, I was unable to find documentation on how to control the logging
with that class.

(cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig)
says how to put into one's application.  Note, they write
"register a ServletContextListener in web.xml."  Presume that last one should
have been `appengine-web.xml`.